# Working with directories

Tags: python, directory

This is my first time trying to get together a program that uses directory in python.

In the sub-directory of my current directory there is a directory called `letters/` and it contains children's letters to Santa Claus.

The program should be written in a way where it's in a certain directory like `c:/python/exercise5/solved.py`. The letters are located in the sub-directory `c:/python/exercise5/letters` and it contains this: `c:/python/exercise5/letters/john.txt`

The files only contain list of things that each child wished for. So the content of the file `john.txt` for example is:

```
notebook, toy car, t-shirt
```

What I am trying to do is create a function that receives the name of a child and returns the list of items that a child desires. To do that, the function must read the correct file from the sub-directory "letters".

So it looks kinda like this

```
read_file("john") {'notebook', 'toy car', 't-shirt'}
```

Next up I want to create a function that doesn't receive any argument, but it returns the `{ }` containing names of all the children, that wrote Santa a letter.

Like this

```
names = senders() >>> names {'dana', 'emma', 'kerry', 'john', 'tom'}
```

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: can you show how file look like??, like child-name item1 item2 ...

Comment: So only one `John` can write a letter to Santa? That's not nice for the many `John`s out there... **:-D** On a more serious note, you should show a more particular example on what you have done so far, what errors are you getting, how are you planning to approach this...

Comment: Something that might get you started (at least for your `senders` function): https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [os module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). It provides functions for listing a directory, deleting them, etc, ex

```
os.listdir("c:\\python27\\Lib\\site-packages")
```

Will return you a list of files and folders in folder `site-packages`.

I don't know a letter file should look like, but I will assume it is a plain text file containing words separated by spaces, like this:

```
notebook toy-car tshirt
```

Then you can just read file's contents and do `file_contents.split()`, which will return you a list containing words ['notebook', 'toy-car', 'tshirt'], for more info take a look at the [string module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sub-directory `letters` of the current directory `c:/python/exercise5` you can simply use a relative path to open the file for a particular child:

```
import os.path

BASE_DIR = ''        # set this if you want a fixed base directory
LETTERS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'letters')

def read_file(child_name):
    '''Returns a list of items requested by the given child'''
    filename = '{}.txt'.format(os.path.join(LETTERS_DIR, child_name))
    with open(filename) as f:
        return set([s.strip() for s in next(f).split(',')])    # only reads the first line
```

The list of senders is simply a matter of getting the file names from the `letters` directory and removing the `.txt` extension:

```
import os

def senders():
    return set([filename[:-4] for filename in os.listdir(LETTERS_DIR) if filename.endswith('.txt')])
```

Note that both functions return a list, not a dictionary as suggested in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well the instructions say that the end result should contain these colons { }

Each text file contains few items one in each line

Like this:

john.txt

notebook 
toy car
t-shirt

Comment: This is not an answer. Please add clarifications to your original question.